# Getting specific elements in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get the elements displayed as N06D-X N07X R01A-C01 S01G-X01 in the following image:[image: HTML snapshot]

Now, I got something like the WebDriver in this way:

`who = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("span").find_elements_by_tag_name("p")`

and get an output like this:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1c044455cf883fdedf6845bcd456bfab", element="0.23338884730774767-2")>]
```

I am working on Mac Catalina and when I type: who.text it returns an empty list for some reason. I got quite similar troubles with Bs but I solved them with `.string` rather than `.text`. Here `.string` does not work on WebDriver elements.

The question is: how can I get the items N06D and so on with selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close enough.

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1c044455cf883fdedf6845bcd456bfab", element="0.23338884730774767-2")>]
```

represents the element where as you were looking for the text within the element.

To extract the texts e.g. *N06D-X*, *N07X*, etc from all of the `<p>` tags using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.data-list__property#who-atc-codes span.data-list__property-value p")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='data-list__property' and @id='who-atc-codes']//span[@class='data-list__property-value']//p")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thank you all. @DebanjanB what does `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located()` do? I mean how does it work? It seems a pretty useful tool actually. It seems that you ask to wait 20 seconds untile the condition in EC. is matched

Comment: `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` is the [`expected_conditions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) used with [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) which halts the execution of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) till the element is displayed & also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

you dont search in whole website but in previously found object

```py
li_object = driver.find_elements_by_id('who-atc-codes')
lst = li_object.find_element_by_tag_name("span").find_elements_by_tag_name("p")

for p in lst:
    print(p.text)
    print(p.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

or you can try

```py
span_object = li_object.find_element_by_tag_name("span")
print(span_object.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: Ok. But now how can I get the .text and then all elements inside (i.e. N06D and so on) specifically? Maybe li_object[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")? But then how can I get N06D and so on? Maybe something like: for i in range(len(who)):
    print(who[i].get_attribute("innerHTML")) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use following `css selector` to get list of items and then iterate.

To get the text You can use either `.text` or `.get_attribute("innterHTML")` or `.get_attribute("textContent")`

**Code:**

```
items=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.data-list__property-value>p")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
    print(item.get_attribute("innterHTML"))
    print(item.get_attribute("textContent"))
    #To get only value from string use spilt and take the first element.
    print(item.text.strip().split(" ")[0])
    print(item.get_attribute("innterHTML").strip().split(" ")[0])
    print(item.get_attribute("textContent").strip().split(" ")[0])
```