# How to scrape the comments using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I want to extract 'comment' from a website. I already tried using selenium and extract it using xpath but it not works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
            
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5307853/ri-disebut-punya-risiko-korupsi-yang-tinggi?_ga=2.13736693.357978333.1608782559-293324864.1608782559')
            
userid_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmt66364625"]/div[1]/div[1]/text()')[0]
userid = userid_element.text
```

This the result :

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-151acf07e320> in <module>
----> 1 userid_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmt66364625"]/div[1]/div[1]/text()')[0]
      2 userid = userid_element.text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

i tried to delete the list index

```
userid_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmt66364625"]/div[1]/div[1]/text()')
userid = userid_element.text
```

but the result is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-890ba28d7494> in <module>
      1 userid_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmt66364625"]/div[1]/div[1]/text()')
----> 2 userid = userid_element.text

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape the comments from the [website](https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5307853/ri-disebut-punya-risiko-korupsi-yang-tinggi?_ga=2.13736693.357978333.1608782559-293324864.1608782559) as the comments are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired [`visibility_of_all_elements_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068370/getting-specific-elements-in-selenium/64071682#64071682).
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5307853/ri-disebut-punya-risiko-korupsi-yang-tinggi?_ga=2.13736693.357978333.1608782559-293324864.1608782559')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.xcomponent-component-frame.xcomponent-visible")))
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='comment__cmt_'][style]")))])
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5307853/ri-disebut-punya-risiko-korupsi-yang-tinggi?_ga=2.13736693.357978333.1608782559-293324864.1608782559')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='xcomponent-component-frame xcomponent-visible']")))
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'comment__cmt_')][@style]")))])
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['buzzer pada kmenaa..giliran muhammdiyah ampe 400an komen..dapseeee\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', 'selama korupsi tidak dihukum mati disanalah korupsi masih liar dan ada kalaupun dibuat hukum mati setidaknya bisa mengurangi angka korupsi itu\nLaporkan\n2BalasBagikan:  ', 'kalo terindikasi korupsi, lalu teriak saya pancasila, biar pd takut\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', '1. Hukuman fisik diperberat. Hukuman sosial diadakan.\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', 'Padahal fokus tegakan hukum dan berantas korupsi otomatis ekonomi terangkat. Hukum tegak ekonomi kuat. Bayangkan setingkat RT aja korupsi. Dan herannya koruptor serasa lebih dihormatin dari pelaku kejahatan lain.\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', 'Bikin UU cashless aja Bu. Transaksi cash maks 1jt. Jadi lebih enak ditracing\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', 'Hukum terlalu lemah, yang pernah korupsi malah masih menjabat pemerintahaan dan malah masih mencalonkan diri sebagai bupati atau walikota dan gubernur setelah melakukan korupsi.\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', 'system birokrasi yg lemah, seharusnya mulai mengandalkan teknologi kontrol online untuk mengurangi kesempatan pejabat yg korupsi\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', 'Bukan cuma resiko, emang udah kejadian kaleeee hahahhahahaha\nLaporkan\n0BalasBagikan:  ', 'ga heran jamannya new orba\nLaporkan\n1BalasBagikan:  ']
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

```
userid = [i.text for i in userid_element]
print(userid)
```

Find_elemnts returns a list you have to iterate through each element . You can use above code to iterate and get text from each element and store it an array

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the comments you can do like this

```
comment_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='comment__cmt_box_text___3bK3O comment__cmt_dk_komen___1Yzyg']")
comments = [comment.text for comment in comment_elements]
```