# Find total numbers of urls

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, mousehover

I write script in python for getting multiple urls. Multiple urls are print in console,but i want when multiple urls are print in console then show total number of urls.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files\Python39\libs\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
url = ("https://www.libertybooks.com/")
driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(5)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="cc-btn cc-allow"]').click()
Non_fiction = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul/li[2][@class="top_level dropdown"]/a').click()

for i in range(30):
 multiple_urls = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@class="img-responsive reg-image"]').get_attribute('src')
 print(multiple_urls)
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-count-the-total-number-of-links-in-selenium-with-python Did you even google this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The last part of your code needs several modifications:

In:

```
for i in range(30):
    multiple_urls = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@class="img-responsive reg-image"]').get_attribute('src')
    print(multiple_urls)
```

the xpath `'//img[@class="img-responsive reg-image"]'` refers to several images, so you should use a function to get the list of theses images, which is "*driver.find_element**s**_by_xpath*" and not "*driver.find_element_by_xpath*" which i used for one element (**elements and not element**).

so you need to modify that part to:

```
multiple_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[@class="img-responsive reg-image"]')
```

now you can get the number of images by:

```
print(len(multiple_urls))
```

and, then print the URLs by:

```
for url in multiple_urls:
    print(url.get_attribute('src'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of total number of urls you have to [Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003) the element with text as **Non Fiction** inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [`visibility_of_all_elements_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068370/getting-specific-elements-in-selenium/64071682#64071682) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.libertybooks.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='cc-btn cc-allow']"))).click()
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='top_level dropdown']//a[contains(., 'Non Fiction')]")))).perform()
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='top_level dropdown']//a[contains(., 'Non Fiction')]//following::div[1]//ul[contains(@class, 'list-unstyled')]//ul//a")))))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  34
  ```